# format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’

Tags: c, printf

I'm using Linux and when I try using this code to display:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    int result;

    printf( "How Many Times Would You Like to Add: ");
    scanf( "%d", &a );
    //getchar();

    printf( "What Number Would You Like to Add: ");
    scanf( "%d", &b );
    //getchar();

    printf( "What Number Would You Like to Add to It?: ");
    scanf( "%d", &c );
    //getchar();

    for( int $i = 0; $i < a; $i++ )
    {
        result = b + c;
        printf( "%d", &result );
        printf( "\n" );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I get this:

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:26:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat]
```

Using this compilation command:

```
cd ./TSTS
gcc -std=c99 main.c -o LetsADD!
```

Comment: `printf( "%d", &result );` causes that warning. What is the type of `&result`? What is the type of `result`? Why might `printf` want an `int` (and hence the warning) while `scanf` wants an `int*`? (Hint: what does each function *need* to do?)

Comment: As it says: %d expects an integer. You're passing it a pointer to (the address of) an integer. Get rid of the `&` character; you don't need or want it here.

Comment: @firstposter thank you for showing me the way their, your answer was all i needed and it was fixed in 2 minutes (almost all from typing the wrong things in the terminal on this small keyboard) poster2: thank you but i had it figured out from user one i was hoping more for someone to not flat out tell me

Comment: @user3272334 Rather than hope for someone not to detail the solution, simple post the level of help you want up front.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for( int $i = 0; $i < a; $i++ )
```

Remove the `$` here. This isn't PHP.

```
    printf( "%d", &result );
```

Remove the `&` here. `printf` takes a value, not a pointer. `&` gets the address of a variable. (Note that `scanf` *does* take a pointer, because C uses pass-by-value, and `scanf` needs to modify the value.)

Comment: lol that is the funniest coding mistake ive ever made

Comment: is address of a variable not a value?